# Map a Rails Custom SQL Query to an ActiveRecord Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm setting up a custom query that uses a range of OR statements in conjunction with BETWEEN statements and a final GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) >= #{tolerance}. Not to mention INNER and LEFT join operations.

I would assume that it would not be possible to setup using active record. So I used the Model.connection.select_all() command to fire a query. This works, but how do I not map all of the rows to that specific model?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rails is pretty powerful especially if you are using Rails 3 & ARel. So I wouldn't be surprised if you actually *could* write your query using rails.

However, there will always be times when writing raw SQL is desired.

To do that, instead of Model.connection use `Model.find_by_sql(QUERY_STRING)`.

This way the query will get parsed for you automatically just make sure you only `select "model.*"`

Comment: This is probably the best solution, to go further, if you are using PostgreSQL, you might want to create a view for this query : see [KnowSQL presentation](http://knowsql.heroku.com/#1) slide between 70 and 72